# A basic measure theory question

Tags: measure-theory

I have to prove that if $f$ is integrable on $\Bbb R^d$, real-valued, and $\int_E f(x)\, dx \geq 0$ for every measurable set $E$, then $f(x) \geq 0$ a.e. $x$.

I don't understand where integrability of $f$ is used here ?

Comment: If $f$ were not integrable, what would the expression $\int_{E} f(x) dx$ mean?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: To make sense of lebesgue integral we just need one of positive/negative part to be finite. We are not using DCT anywhere here, MCT suffices.

Comment: All right, then if $f = 1_A$ for a non-measurable set $A$, then what is $\int_{\Bbb R^d} f(x)\,dx$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : If $f\ge0$ almost everywhere and $f$ is measurable then $\int_E f(x)\,dx$ is a well defined object, either a nonnegative real number or $+\infty$.  But if it's equal to $\infty$ then $f$ is not integrable by the usual definitions.  It is not necessary for $f$ to be integrable in order that that integral be defined. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy all right, I agree that "measurable" could validly be substituted for "integrable" in this question statement.  However, without either word, we have no reason to assume $f$ is even measurable.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : You seem confused.  If $f=1_A$ for some non-measurable set $A\subseteq\mathbb R^d$, then $\int_{\mathbb R^d} f$ is meaningless.  But nothing in the question suggests that non-measurable sets may be considered.  The function $x\mapsto1/|x|$ is not integrable, but its integral over $\mathbb R$ exists (and is $\infty$). ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : "measurable" CANNOT be substituted for "integrable" in this question.  Where did you get that? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I read the question as saying: "Where do we use the hypothesis that $\int_{\mathbb R^d} |f|<\infty\text{ ?}$". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @user148951: most of the time, mathematicians are just lazy and don't bother about minimal hypotheses.

Comment: @Siméon : I think in this kind of thing, most mathematicians, most mathematicians would bother.  But not this time, it seems.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is measurable and the set $E=\{x\in\mathbb R^d : f(x)<0\}$ has positive measure, then $$
\int_E f < 0.
$$

So the hypothesis that $f$ is integrable can be weakened to the hypothesis that $f$ is measurable.  This proposition has needlessly strong hypotheses.  Sometimes it's a good idea to include hypotheses that can be dropped in order to have a simpler proof, but this doesn't look like such a case.

Comment: If you weaken the hypothesis from integrable to measurable, don't you have to slightly complicate the statement by writing something like "$\int_E f$ is defined and $\geq 0$ for every measurable set $E$"?  (Maybe writing $\int_E f \geq 0$ carries the implicit assertion that the integral *is* defined, by some convention, but I'm not sure that this is a standard convention in introductory measure-theory texts, and I'm not sure it would be a good one either.  It seems safer to me to be explicit about it.)  Perhaps this is a complication the question author was trying to avoid?

Comment: @Bungo : Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: @guy-in-seoul : I took the statement that $\int_E f\ge0$ to mean that $\int_E f$ is defined and $\ge 0$.  But if we allow $\int_E f=+\infty$ in some cases, the conclusion we're after is still true and still proved in the same way (unless some other method of proof was contemplated by whoever wrote the question).

Comment: @MichaelHardy how would i show that $f$ is measurable and $m(E)>0$ then $\int_E f <0$? Use the simple functions definition?